# SQL Server: date range at a specific time in time zone on specific day

Tags: sql-server, timezone, where-in

I use the following `WHERE` condition in SQL Server to determine a date range from Friday (midnight) till Saturday (midnight) from previous week in a specific time zone (here Kuwait)

```
WHERE 
    MYDATE BETWEEN (DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 4) AT TIME ZONE  'Arab Standard Time') 
               AND (DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 5) AT TIME ZONE  'Arab Standard Time')
```

If I had to select `MYDATE` from midnight Friday until Saturday at 5:00 am Kuwait time, how should I proceed to add the extra hours/minutes to the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming** that `MYDATE` is a `datetimeoffset`:

When using a `datetimeoffset` you can include the timezone in the date and SQL Server will handle it. For example the below `CASE` expression returns the value of `@SomeDate`:

```
DECLARE @SomeDate datetimeoffset = '2019-12-28T20:30:31+00:00';

SELECT CASE WHEN @SomeDate >= '2019-12-28T21:00:00+01:00' AND @SomeDate < '2019-12-28T22:00:00+01:00' THEN @SomeDate END;
```

Assuming that the query you are running is from a location in Arab Standard Time, the you're better off using `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET` rather than `GETDATE()` for this, as it returns a `datetimeoffset` as well:

```
WHERE MYDATE >= DATEADD(DAY,5,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 6, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()), 0))
      AND MYDATE < DATEADD(HOUR,5,DATEADD(DAY,6,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 6, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()), 0)))
```

*Note, `DATEADD` with `WEEK` is language dependant, and I don't know what you're settings are, so this may not give you the value you want, but will be in the right ball park*.

If `MYDATE` is a UTC time (another common way of dealing with data when in multiple timezones), and not a `datetimeoffset`, then you can use `SWITCHOFFSET` to change the time after you've created them:

```
WHERE MYDATE >= SWITCHOFFSET(DATEADD(DAY,5,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 6, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()), 0)),'+00:00')
      AND MYDATE < SWITCHOFFSET(DATEADD(HOUR,5,DATEADD(DAY,6,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 6, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()), 0))),'+00:00')
```